# Defining a type on a list that begins with a particular symbol

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to use generic functions' ability to specify behaviour based on the first argument of a list.

In other words, I want the list `(atypelist 1 2 3)` and the list `(btypelist 1 2 3)` to have their individual behaviour when passed to `foo`. So far, this is what I came up with:

```
(deftype atypelist (lst)
  `(eq (car ,lst) 'atypelist))

(deftype btypelist (lst)
  `(eq (car ,lst) 'btypelist))

(defmethod foo ((lst atypelist))
  (format nil "success atypelist: ~S" lst))

(defmethod foo ((lst btypelist))
  (format nil "success btypelist: ~S" lst))
```

However, when I call `(typep (list 'atypelist 1 2 3) 'atypelist)` I get the following error:

```
error while parsing arguments to DEFTYPE ATYPELIST:
  too few elements in
    ()
  to satisfy lambda list
    (LST):
  exactly 1 expected, but got 0
```

I am guessing the error is in my definition of `atypelist`.

Questions:

- **Is there a better way to get the functionality I am looking for?**
- **If yes - what is the way?**
- **If not - how to properly define a type on a list/cons that has a particular symbol in the `car`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I start: what you want to do can't work, and is confused in two ways.

**Firstly** `deftype` defines a type in terms of other type specifiers: the body of a `deftype` form must expand into a type specifier, not an expression, as yours does. And `deftype`'s arguments are not the thing you want to check the type for, they are parts of the type specification.

In this case you want to specify that the thing is a [`cons`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_cons.htm), and that its car is [`eql`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_eql.htm) to something.  Fortunately there are specializing type specifiers for both of these things, and you end up with something like this:

```
(deftype cons-with-specified-car (x)
  `(cons (eql ,x) t))
```

And now

```
> (typep '(1) '(cons-with-specified-car 1))
t

> (typep '(a) '(cons-with-specified-car a))
t

> (typep '() '(cons-with-specified-car a))
nil
```

And if you want:

```
(deftype cons-with-a ()
  '(cons-with-specified-car a))
```

and now

```
> (typep '(a) 'cons-with-a)
t
```

**Secondly** none of this will work because this it not how CLOS works.  CLOS dispatches on *classes* not types, and you have merely defined a type, not a class: your method definitions simply cannot work, since classes cannot be parametrized in this way like types can.

**Some ways you might achieve what you want.**

If what you want to do is to dispatch on the first element of a list, then the obvious approach, if you want to use CLOS, is to use a two-level approach where you first dispatch on the class of the thing (`cons` is a class), and then use `eql` specializers to pick out the things you want.

```
(defgeneric select (it)
  (:method ((it cons))
   (select* (car it) it))
  (:method (it)
   nil))

(defgeneric select* (key it)
  (:method (key it)
   (format t "~&unknown key ~S in ~S~%" key it)))

(defmethod select* ((key (eql 'a)) it)
  (format t "~&~S begins with a~%" it))
```

However in a case like this, *unless you very much want the extensibility that CLOS gets you* (which is a good reason to use CLOS here), I'd just use `typecase`.  You could do this using the type defined above:

```
(defun select (it)
  (typecase it
    ((cons-with-specified-car a)
     '(cons a))
    (cons
     'cons)
    (t
     nil)))
```

or, probably simpler, just use what the `deftype` expands into:

```
(defun select (it)
  (typecase it
    ((cons (eql a) t)
     '(cons a))
    (cons
     'cons)
    (t
     nil)))
```

Finally probably what anyone doing this would actually write (again, assuming you do not want the extensibility CLOS gets you) is:

```
(defun select (it)
  (typecase it
    (cons
     (case (car it)
       ...))
    (t
     ...)))
```

Comment: Great answer! Can you please help me understand `(cons (eql ,x) t))`? I am guessing `cons` refers to the fact that we expect cons, however `(eql ,x)` and `t` don't make sense to me. Also, why do we need the body of the `deftype` to be an s-expression? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, using the type specifier [`satisfies`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_satisf.htm#satisfies):

```
CL-USER> (defun is-atypelist (list)
           (eq (car list) 'atypelist))
IS-ATYPELIST
CL-USER> (defun is-btypelist (list)
           (eq (car list) 'btypelist))
IS-BTYPELIST
CL-USER> (deftype atypelist ()
           `(satisfies is-atypelist))
ATYPELIST
CL-USER> (deftype btypelist ()
           `(satisfies is-btypelist))
BTYPELIST
CL-USER> (typep (list 'atypelist 1 2 3) 'atypelist)
T
CL-USER> (typep (list 'atypelist 1 2 3) 'btypelist)
NIL
```

Note that this does **not** define a class, but a type, if this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to get the functionality I am looking for?

#### 1. Wrap your lists in container types

```
(defclass lst () ((items :initarg :items :reader items)))

(defclass alst (lst) ())
(defclass blst (lst) ())
```

It may be a little bit more cumbersome to work with but this is pretty much straightforward and not too suprising.

#### 2. Douple-dispatch

```
(defgeneric foo (val))
(defgeneric foo/tag (tag val))
```

For example:

```
(defmethod foo ((c cons))
  (destructuring-bind (tag . list) c
    (foo/tag tag list)))
```

#### 3. Define a custom method combination

It should be possible to hack the meta-object protocol dispatch mechanism to dispatch on the first item of a list. I wouldn't recommend it however.

#### 4. Use a different dispatch mechanism

Use a completely different dispatching mechanism outside of CLOS, like `pprint-dispatch` does. For example you may want to use `trivia` or `optima` pattern-matching libraries, or *cl-algebraic-data-type*. This may be more useful if you are dealing with trees of symbols.